# How is parameter "weights" used in KNeighborsClassifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, knn

In *sklearn* documentation, the parameter `weights="distance"` of function *KNeighborsClassifier* is explained as follows:

> ‘**distance**’ : weight points by the inverse of their distance. in this case, closer neighbors of a query point will have a greater
>   influence than neighbors which are further away.

While it make sense to me to weight neighboring points and then calculate the prediction as mean of weighted points, for instance using *KNeighborsRegressor*... However, I cannot see how weight is used in a classification algorithms. According to the book *The Elements of Statistical Learning*, the KNN classification is based on majority vote. Isn't it?

Comment: KNN being majority vote is not something that is set on stone. Majority vote is the simplest decision making strategy here and by far the easiest to implement. However, as you mentioned, introducing distances as weights is plausible since majority vote discards valuable distance information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During Classification, the weights would be used when computing the mode of neighbors (Instead of frequency, sum of the weights would be used to compute mode).

To know more details from look [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb/sklearn/neighbors/classification.py#L165), for the actual implementation.

Examples from [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.extmath.weighted_mode.html):

```
>>> from sklearn.utils.extmath import weighted_mode
>>> x = [4, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2]
>>> weights = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
>>> weighted_mode(x, weights)
(array([4.]), array([3.]))
The value 4 appears three times: with uniform weights, the result is simply the mode of the distribution.

>>>
>>> weights = [1, 3, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 2]  # deweight the 4's
>>> weighted_mode(x, weights)
(array([2.]), array([3.5]))
```

You can view the implementation [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7813f7efb5b2012412888b69e73d76f2df2b50b6/sklearn/utils/extmath.py#L360)